# What do I miss in understanding 1NF

Tags: normalization

I have a nooby question regarding 1NF.
As I read from different sources a table is in the 1NF if it contains no repeating groups. 
I understand this with the examples given online (usually with customers and contact names etc) but when it comes to my specific data I face difficulties.

I have the following fields:

```
 ID  TOW  RECEIVER Phi01_L1 Phi01_L2 Phi01_L3
  1  4353  gpo1     0.007   0.006     0.4
  2  4353  gpo1     0.9     0.34      0.3
```

So, this table here is not in 1NF? How should it be in order to become?

Comment: Phi01_L1 Phi01_L2 Phi01_L3 kind of smell like "repeating groups", don't they?  Can you divide this into four separate tables (ID, TWO, RECEIVER_, (ID, L1), (ID, L2) and (ID, L3)?

Comment: Ok. But then if I have similar fields like SNR_L1/SNR_L2/SNR_L3 and Lc_L1/Lc_L2/Lc_L3...etc then I will have to make really a lot of tables...Isn't it like, that I loose performance then if I try to join all these tables??

Comment: As a matter of fact, "yes".  There is often tension between "normalization" and "performance" - "denormalizing" your schema can often *simplify* it.  Often times, it can also *increase* performance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### What is Fist normal form (1NF)?

1NF- Disallows:

1. composite attributes
2. multivalued attributes
3. and nested relations; attributes whose values for an individual tuple are non-atomic

### How to convert a relation into 1NF?

Two ways to convert into 1 NF:

1. **Expand relation:**

   - Increase number of colons in relation (as you did)
   - Increase rows and change Primary key value. (PK will include non-atomic attribute)

   Hence **your** `relation looks in 1-NF` in **present relation-state.** and solution you made is expansion.
2. **Break Relation:**

   - Break relation into two relations -e.g. remove non-atomic col from base relation and create a new relation and add to new with PK.

Normal forms are best explain in [Elmasri/Navath](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=1%20normal%20navathe%20dbms&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CCUQFjAB&url=http://www.cse.hcmut.edu.vn/%7Ettqnguyet/DatabaseSystem/Reference/ENCh08.ppt&ei=bzmhUPOjJofMrQf8wYGABQ&usg=AFQjCNEEBCUcGOxgCSBCUVTKMGa2KGve0A) book